# two questions about outerplanar graph while working on a 3 color problem of the graph

Tags: coloring

[Fisk's short proof about triangulating outerplanar graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Art_gallery_problem#Fisk's_short_proof)

[Second problem has a solution using the fact that outerplanar graph has at least one vertex with degree of at most 2](http://sma.epfl.ch/~moric/gt2013/sol7.pdf)

I am wondering, how can the outerplanar graph can be triangulated as introduced in the wiki, and how I can prove that outerplanar graph has at least one vertex with degree of at most 2.

For the first question, by algorighm explained in the wiki, one can prove that the graph is 3-colorable.

For the second question, by induction on number of vertices, the graph is 3-colorable.

However, to use any of those, I need to prove that they are actually right. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1) Wherever you see a face with more than three sides, add an edge across the face connecting two vertices that were not already connected. Keep going until every face has only 3 sides.

(2) Choose an arbitrary interior edge. Since it connects two points on the exterior of the graph, it divides the graph into two parts. Choose one of the parts. Pick an interior edge in that part. It divides the graph again. Pick the part that does not contain the first edge. Keep going in this way, always picking the part not containing your previously chosen edges. As there are only finitely many edges, eventually this has to stop - there are no more interior edges on one side of your final pick. But since faces with two edges only are not allowed, the face on that side has to have at least one more vertex. Any such vertex cannot have an interior edge connecting to it, so it can only have the two exterior edges. I.e., its degree is $2$.